# Is It Necessary to Return a Value in Main()?

Tags: c, return-type

I was just writing a quick program for calculating some things when I came across the return statement/exit statement for the C program.

I declared `main()` to be of type `int`, so I would have to put in a return of an integer, or my program would not compile correctly. However, is it acceptable to make `main` a `Boolean` or even `void`?

I know the standard way to create a C program is to return a value so any problems can be sorted out, among other things, but wouldn't a `Boolean` work the same way? Also, could I get away with declaring it `void` and not having problems with the operating system still running my program after it has been terminated?

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c?rq=3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C99 standard says: (§5.1.2.2.1 *Program startup*)

> The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no
>   prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a **return type of int** and with no
>   parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent; or in some other implementation-defined manner.

So in a hosted environment, `int` is the only valid, standard return type. Implementations can define other entry points though.

Note that section §5.1.2.2.3 *Program Termination* has this:

> If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, a return from the
>   initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value
>   returned by the main function as its argument; **reaching the } that terminates the
>   main function returns a value of 0**. If the return type is not compatible with int, the
>   termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.

So you omitting a return from `main` is legal in C99, as long as your `main` returns an `int`.
(But previous versions of the C standard didn't have that exception for `main` - returning no value (or reaching the final `}` without a return statement) causes "*the termination status returned to the host environment [to be] undefined*.".)

Comment: `or in some other implementation-defined manner` --> this leaves much room for interpretation :-)

Comment: @jdehaan: Not really; "implementation-defined" means something that's explicitly documented by the implementation.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in C90, reaching the `}` returns an undefined status.

Answer (score 5):

Summary: You don't necessarily have to, but you should **if** your code might be compiled with a pre-C99 compiler.

In C90, reaching the end of `main()` without executing a `return` statement means "the termination status returned to the host environment is undefined".  On at least one system I've used, the status returned is 1, which on that system indicate that the program failed.

C99 added a new rule, saying that reaching the end of `main()` returns 0.  (C++ has the same rule.)  Not all compilers fully implement C99, and those that do often don't behave as conforming C99 compilers by default. (Added 10 years later: The conformance situation is better now, and most modern C compilers support at least C99.)

The only portable values you can return from `main()` are 0, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and `EXIT_FAILURE` (the latter two are defined in `<stdlib.h>`.  0 and `EXIT_SUCCESS` indicate that the program succeeded (and `EXIT_SUCCESS` is usually defined as 0); `EXIT_FAILURE` indicates that the program failed.  `return 1;` is common, but non-portable; I've worked on a system (VMS), where a termination status of 1 indicates success.  If you want your program to be portable, use `EXIT_FAILURE` to indicate failure; that's what it's for.  Some systems and program define other system-specific or application-specific status codes.

For portability (and, IMHO, style), it's best to do an explicit `return 0;` at the end of `main()`, though it's not required in all circumstances.  It's much easier to add that one line of code (which is, at worst, harmless) than to waste time determining whether you need it.

(Update 10 years later: I no longer think it's important to do an explicit `return 0;` *unless* you have a requirement for your code to work with old compilers or with current compilers configured to conform to the old C90 standard.)

Note that the correct definitions for `main()` are:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

or equivalent (for example, you can write `char **argv` rather than `char *argv[]`).  It's questionable whether `int main() { /* ... */ }` is valid, for subtle reasons I won't go into here, but I believe all compilers accept it.  Again, it's easier to add the `void` keyword than to waste time determining whether you need it.

A lot of books and tutorials use `void main()` or `void main(void)`.  A particular compiler may choose to permit this, but it's not portable.  Seeing `void main` in a book or tutorial is a good sign that the author doesn't know the C standard very well, and that you should find something else to study.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [link](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/legality-of-void-main.html) that might be of interest. Seems the answer to your question is not that straight. I've also seen compilers (MS Visual C) accepting `void` as a return type.

Comment: There is a difference between "hosted" and "freestanding" implementations. The OP should be considered a hosted implementation, and so he should stick to the standard. Borland, Microsoft and Herb Schildt may pollute the language with their own semantics, but they should not name it "standard".

Answer (score 0):

The code that calls main() expects it to return int (or call exit()). You cannot change the code that calls main() *(it is part of the OS or runtime)*, so you'd better return int.

Answer (score 0):

The standard, per ISO, is to return an int.  See section 5.1.2.2.1 of this document: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf.  Also interesting is Stroustrup's commentary on this matter related to both C and C++: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#void-main.

Answer (score 0):

The return type must be `int`, as covered by other answers. However your assumption that you must return a value at all because of this is wrong, `main` is an exception. The C99 standard provides for this, so it is perfectly fine to implement main without using `return`.

Answer (score 0):

In ANSI C, `main ()` usually has a return type of `int`, but it can actually be implementation-defined; this means that different compilers and platforms accept different signatures, but `int main ()` and `int main (int, char**)` are *guaranteed* by the standard to be well-formed.

It is unlike other non-void functions, in that it doesn't need a `return` statement. In the case that none is supplied, and the return type is specified as `int`, then the program is compiled as if there were an implicit `return 0;` after the last statement in `main ()`.

The relevant part of the standard:

> **5.1.2.2.3 Program termination**
>
> *1* If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`, a `return` from the
>   initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value
>   returned by the `main` function as its argument; reaching the `}` that terminates the
>   `main` function returns a value of `0`. If the return type is not compatible with `int`, the
>   termination status returned to the host environment is unspeciﬁed.

Don't quote me on this, but in K+R, however, things were a little looser, and I *think* you didn't even need to specify a return type, so `main () { }` is actually a valid K+R program.

Comment: `int main(void)`, not `int main()`.  And in K&R C (and in 1989 ANSI C / 1990 ISO C), if you omit the return type it defaults to `int`.  That rule was dropped in the 1999 ISO C standard.  It's never a good idea to take advantage of it.