# Are there any difference between s++ and *s++?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm a beginner in C and Let's say I have a code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void test(char *t)
{
     t++;
    *t = 'e';
}

void main()
{
    char a[] = "anto";
    printf("%c\n",a[1]);
    test(a);
    printf("%c\n",a[1]);
}
```

This is the sample code, where I am figuring out how pointers work. According to me the statement:

```
t++;
```

in the above code will increment the address of array `a` by `1` `char` in the calling function `test`. Fine, now as far I know the `*` is used to retrieve the object value that the pointer points to.

But weirdly when I change the `t++` to

```
*t++;
```

I'm getting the same output as before. I'm literally confused with this, the above statement 
`*t++;` should change the contents only know, according to the definition of `*` operator.

But again this changes the address of `t`. How come? Where I'm getting the concept wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note: always compile with warnings enabled, e.g. `gcc -Wall`. and *read and take notice of* those warnings

Comment: IIRC doing math on a null pointer just has an undefined result, whereas dereferencing a null pointer has undefined behaviour. So there's a difference, but it only shows up if t is null.

Comment: Side note: You should be using `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char** argv)` instead of `void main()`

Comment: @another.anon.coward: I always find people saying this, are there any specific reason for it?

Comment: Answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376421/is-it-necessary-to-return-a-value-in-main might provide you with some pointers as to why. You will be able find a few more related questions on SO

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The expression `*t++` is parsed as `*(t++)` -- the `++` still applies to the pointer, not the contents. The value of `t++` is the value of the pointer itself before the increment, while the value of `*t++` is what the pointer points to before the increment.

Comment: Although this is correct I don't think it really answers the OP's question

Comment: @PaulR 1. it does. 2. (to everyone): this is why you can this trick even with a `const char *`, as you couldn't increment a const value, but you can do so with a pointer to it.

Answer (score 4):

(*) operator is used to dereference a pointer.

```
t++;
```

as a statement returns the previous position of the pointer where as

```
*t++;
```

returns the value that the t pointer is pointed to before incrementing it.

The side effects of both statements are same, so you are getting the same output.

```
*t++;
```

statement does not change the value t is pointing to because ++ operator has greater precedence then * operator.

Answer (score 2):

`++` has greater precedence than `*` so your expression evaluates to `*(t++)`.

Answer (score 1):

Postfix `++` has higher precedence than unary `*`, so `*t++` is parsed as `*(t++)`; you're dereferencing the result of the expression `t++`; as a side effect, `t` is advanced.

Unary `*` and unary `++` have the *same* precedence, so if they appear in the same expression they would be evaluated left-to-right.  The expression `*++t` would be parsed as `*(++t)`; you dereference the result of the expression `++t`, and as a side effect `t` is advanced.

`++*t` would be parsed as `++(*t)`; you're incrementing the result of the expression `*t`.